Integration of Differential Forms
I am reading the book "Lee, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" in the section on integration, and I encountered a problem with the definition of the integral. The book defines the integral of an
Suppose first that $ \omega $ is compactly supported in the domain of a single smooth chart $(U, \varphi)$ that is either positively or negatively oriented. We define the integral of $ \omega $ over $ M $ to be
$
\int_M \omega = \int_{\varphi(U)} (\varphi^{-1})^*(\omega),
$
Let $ \{ U_i \} $ be a finite open cover of $ \operatorname{supp} \, \omega $ by domains of positively or negatively oriented smooth charts, and let $ \{ \psi_i \} $ be a subordinate smooth partition of unity. Define the integral of $ \omega $ over $ M $ to be
$
\int_M \omega = \sum_i \int_M \psi_i \omega.
$
My question is: what happens if the coordinate system overlaps a lot? In other words, if the coordinate system has many non-empty intersections, wouldn’t the value of the integral increase when calculating it? I don't quite understand how defining the integral in this way resolves that issue. I’m not sure if I explained my question well

Please include the definition and your exact concern here. If I recall correctly you also need to involve a partition of unity, which should take care of this supposed issue

This is what the partition of unity prevents, i.e. you "counter the overlaps" by finding such partition of unity.

Your (and my) natural instinct is to chop up the region of integration into a bunch of “almost” disjoint pieces, integrate over each piece separately and add up all the contributions. This is ingrained in us from the first time we learn integration via Riemann sums (and also Lebesgue).
But the ‘other’ nice feature of integrals is their linearity. So, rather than chopping up the domain into a bunch of pieces, we can instead decompose the integrand into a bunch of pieces, then add up each of their integrals. The purpose of a partition of unity is to accomplish this (and to precisely decompose things nicely… including things like being subordinate to an atlas of charts).
One can actually formalize the statement more into an existence and uniqueness statement: given a smooth $n$-dimensional oriented manifold $M$, there is a unique linear map $I:\Omega^n_c(M)\to \Bbb{R}$, such that for a top-form with compact support in a single coordinate chart, $I$ gives the result we want (integral of the pullback). So no, there’s no overcounting (even intuitively: while there is overlap in the supports, we have different weighted integrands, so there’s still hope for well-defintion; and this theorem says that is indeed true).
I should mention that if you know Lebesgue integration (which is just good all around because we can deal with various kinds of sets, and we have the wonderful dominated convergence theorem), then you should be able to prove an existence and uniqueness theorem for integrals of $L^1$ differential forms, without resorting to partitions of unity. Though, avoiding partitions of unity for the sake of avoiding them isn’t really a good thing, because while they’re not entirely necessary in this case, they are in other situations, and they’re a very powerful technical tool.
